# Django "./manage.py runserver" log to file instead of console

Tags: python, django

Running `python manage.py runserver` will initiate Django's development server and all logs are printed to the console.

I need to write the logs in a `django.log` file instead of console.

[Django logging documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/) is good, but I cant seem to configure the logging to log the same as `python manage.py runserver`.

**Question:** How can I log everything from `./manage.py runserver` to a file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a simple linux redirect, so it should look something like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 >> log.log 2>&1
```

Please note that I've set 8080 as the local port, you should change it according your project.

PS: This method (manage runserver) should be used for development only, **not for deployment**.

Comment: Syntax for using Docker: 
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000 >> log.log 2>&1"]

Comment: What does `2>&1` do?

Comment: The `2>&1` redirects error messages to the regular output

Answer (score 3):

These are some sample settings that should make sure that logs are written to both console and file. You can add/modify this in your dev-settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        # this is what you see in runserver console
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        # this handler logs to file
        #▼▼▼▼ this is just a name so loggers can reference it
        'file': {  
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            #  choose file location of your liking
            'filename': os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../logs/django.log')),  
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # django logger
        'django': {
            # log to console and file handlers
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],  
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'ERROR'),  # choose verbosity
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: This only prints out logging at ERROR log level. The result is therefore not similar to the runserver command. 
I dont know what log level the runserver command uses, please let me know if you find out :)

Comment: DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL is set to 'ERROR'. Set it to 'DEBUG', everything will be logged.